# Calling python function across network

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am doing some image processing (stereo vision) using OpenCV 3.4.0 on Python 2.7. The targeted end device is a single board computer such as a Raspberry Pi.
The problem I am currently facing is the SBC takes too long to process the images and really lowers the fps (maximum I get now is 8 fps). I need a real time system with **atleast 20 fps**. So, I was thinking if it is possible to **run another system with higher capability** in the network and pass the image matrices to it from the SBC. The return value is another matrix.
 Is there a way to call a function over a network?. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. You can transfer data over a network. But it's unlikely to get you the performance you need, simply because of network latency and lag in packing the data for sending and unpacking it on receipt.

Comment: I am using a local network. And the data is not too long. The current problem I am facing  is that the end device has really low processing power.

Comment: Local network doesn't change a lot. There's still some latency. And your question asks about *20 FPS* - that's not *data is not too long* even on a low-resolution device. Do the math - that's one frame every 50 ms. But my comment remains the same: *No. You can transfer data over a network.*.

Comment: Have you explored multiprocessing solutions on the RPi?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do **"Edge Analytics"** at the Raspbery Pi side.

### Cause

Your problem is occurred because both your Client(Raspberry Pi) and Server is having high performance but your network is too slow.

### Solution

You can write a simple Python algorithm to send only the changed bits in a frame, instead of sending the whole data over the network. By the above mentioned method you can reduce your network usage, which helps you in sending more frame(30-60fps) information.

### Terms

- Edge Analytics : It refers to the analysis of data from some non-central point in a system, such as a network switch, peripheral node or connected device or sensor
- Reference url's

  1. http://pythonforengineers.com/image-and-video-processing-in-python/
  2. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my problem correctly. My network is fast but the client is slow. Especially for image processing applications as all work is being done in the CPU. I was asking for a way to do the processing on the server and get the results back at the client.